# How to set up custom domain for an app on Amazon EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns

I am new in the Amazon EC2 world, I just created an app, that is located URL like this:

```
http://ec2-54-123-45-678.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080
```

This is generated URL by Amazon EC2.

Now I would need to use my own domain name, so when I would access **www.my-domain-name.com**, I would like to see the content from

```
http://ec2-54-123-45-678.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080
```

I bought the domain name on Godaddy.
Is there any way to do this in Amazon AWS dashboard or do I need to set it up in Godaddy system?

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

I am answering on a more general level because I stumbled upon this thread when setting my custom domain.

In Amazon I created an instance and associated an IP to that instance. You were able to access it by typing in the amazon url

[image: main]

I actually used Media Temple not GoDaddy, but it will be similar. I went to the zone file and added that public url to the `www`

[image: zone file]

And as you can see, here is my blog actually working on the custom domain.

[image: custom domain]

I set the wildcard because that way, no matter what someone types, if it is not set, then they will still see the site.

[image]

**EDIT**

For the root URL you should be entering your elastic IP and setting that as an A record.

Comment: But this approach has one problem. When you restart your instance the URL could change ... and your domain will not match with it

Comment: @eveevans so what would you do different? I have about 10 domains and constantly restart my instance with no problems. If the URL changed I could quickly diagnose it. But I am interested to know what you would do different, thanks.

Comment: What I do is request an Elastic IP and associate it with an instance, so then I could create an A-Record to that IP.

Comment: @eveevans actually I should update my answer because the bare domain should have the elastic IP in an A record. But when I tried the elastic IP with CNAME for the `www` and wildcard, i had an issue with my DNS host Media Temple.

Comment: @JGallardo to use an IP in the "right" side you must set an A type record using your ElasticIP: www A eip

Comment: @DiegoF.Durán yeah I previously made an edit noting that. See the bottom.

Answer (score 9):

First you need to set an ElasticIP for associated to that instance.

Then point the DNS entry of "www" for "my-domain-name.com" to the IP assigned in the step above.

Where you manage your DNS is another thing, can be in GoDaddy or in AWS Route53. You must adjust the delegation DNS in the "my-domain-name.com" register. Ex: your domain can be registered with GoDaddy but its delegation DNS point to Route53 so you can manage the domain from your AWS Console.

Comment: Thank you for your message, Diego. I've tried it, I created the ElastiIP for the respective EC2 instance, then I pointed the **www** DNS entry for my domain name, but when I open my IURL in the browser, I see there just **Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to my-website.com**. I did this thing like a day or two ago. What am I missing yet? Thanks.

Comment: Is "www.my-website.com" resolving to the ElasticIP?

Comment: No, the same issue (sorry for my late response).

Answer (score 0):

In order to setup DNS mapping you can map the existing IP 54.123.45.678 to **ex:** www.my-domain-name.com.

However, as you are running tomcat which is running at 8080 you need to forward the the request to the tomcat using Apache. So that you can visit www.my-domain-name.com  without port 8080. If you are using linux box install Apache, apache-modjk and then configure sites.

Comment: You must associate an ElasticIP first and map the ElasticIP. The IP listed above can and will change.